# "Unmet dependencies" when installing SQLite driver in PHP7 on 16.04

Tags: apt, php, dependencies, sqlite

This is a bit of a weird one. When I run `sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite3` I get told that

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 php7.0-sqlite3 : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.4-7ubuntu2) but 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However on [the page for php7.0-sqlite3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-sqlite3) then it lists the `7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3` version of `php7.0-common` as a supported dependency. So why is it unable to install?

I've tried running `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, `apt-get install -f`, `apt-get dist-upgrade` and whatnot, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways i'll tell you two

**You first need to install [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-sqlite3) and run the commands through Terminal, and if it still didn't work then try these steps :**

open up Terminal by searching it up or just pressing

**CTRL+ALT+T**

first do

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

then

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and run this again

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

if you get this :

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

then it didn't work then you try this second method

```
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
```

If it shows any held packages, it is best to eliminate them. Packages are held because of dependency conflicts that `apt` cannot resolve. Try this command to find and repair the conflicts:

```
sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
```

then it should look like this

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

if your still getting errors try :

[image: Click here | and make sure they are all ticked]

make sure they are all ticked

Comment: Hm, thanks for the response however on both methods I get told "0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade."

Comment: that means it worked if it its 0 all it means it worked

Comment: I still get the same error when trying to install php7.0-sqlite3 though.

Comment: i edited the post try the new method

Comment: Cheers, still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: thats weird maybe try downloading this package  http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-sqlite3

Comment: and then try doing it through terminal

Comment: woooooooo :D np :)